# PHP Unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm making a basic lotery script and i'm getting the same error the whole time: Unexpected T_Variable on line 5. Here is my script, I hope someone can help me:

```
<?php
        $invulcijfer = '';
        if (isset($_POST['sumbitBtn']))
        {
            $invulcijfer = $_POST['cijfer'];
            $pinda = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $invulcijfer);
            $lotnummer = "1234"; // Hier je 4 cijfers voor lotnummer

            if($invulcijfer = '') {
            echo "<font color='#FF000'>Je moet alles invullen</font>";
        } else if($pinda !== $invulcijfer) {
        echo "<font color='#FF000'>Dat zijn geen cijfers</font>";
        } else {
            if ($pinda == $lotnummer) {
                    echo "<font color='green'>WAUW! Het is je gelukt!</font>";
            } else { 
                    echo "<font color='#FF000'>Sorry, het is niet gelukt..</font>";
                    // Maybe update query van dat ze - points hebben ofso? q wat jij wilt
            }
            }
        }
    }?>
    <br><br>
    <h3>Loterij Script</h3>
    <font color="green">Typ 4 cijfers in en misschien win jij!</font><br><br>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" maxlength="4"/><br>
        <input type="text" id="cijfer" name="cijfer" maxlength="4"/><br>
        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Check je lot"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Try removing your last `}` above `?>` seems it's one too much. Or you can delete one in `}}` instead.

Comment: Well, sometimes Stackoverflow formats my code really weird, I had to space a thousand times to get it like this. So yes it's one script.

Comment: Try indenting that code properly, run the script again, look at the line where it says the error is, and the line above it, and see it you forgot something obvious, most likely you did.

Comment: Well I did that myself, this is the line that is giving the error: $invulcijfer = $_POST['cijfer']; which is in my opinion just correct.

Comment: It does look like you have a closing bracket too much at the end ?

Comment: @adeneo Just like I told the OP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I noticed, was just agreeing with you

Comment: Yes fixed that but still the same error.

Comment: Also, the names for the form fields does not match the POST variables ?

Comment: @adeneo I noticed that too (mismatched names), I'd need to test the code first

Comment: Also, `if ($invulcijfer = '') {...` does not check anything, you'd need more equal signs for that ?

Comment: @adeneo I doubt the OP is done with his/her script. I'm having a hard time trying to decipher just what those 2 fields are supposed to do and match something. Quite bizarre. Maybe the OP wants to use it in conjunction with another file, and is why the OP said was still getting an error. Tested without the extra closing brace, did not give me an error.

Comment: Fixed, thanks to Fred an adeneo. Thank you guys/girls. Really appreciate that.

Comment: Having those var names and comments in a foreign language makes quite hard to follow the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

I spotted a few errors:

THIS:

```
if (isset($_POST['sumbitBtn']))
```

it needs to read as

```
if (isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
```

there was a spelling mistake.

Also `if($invulcijfer = '') {` needs to be `if($invulcijfer == '') {`

---

You have one closing brace too many.

Remove the one this one in `}?>` and your script will work.

This is the code that I ran, deleting the extra closing brace.

### EDIT #2 (fixed conditions and spelling mistake for submit button.

```
<?php

$invulcijfer = '';
  if (isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
  {

$invulcijfer = $_POST['cijfer'];
$pinda = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $invulcijfer); 
$lotnummer = "1234"; // Hier je 4 cijfers voor lotnummer 

if($invulcijfer == '') {

    echo "<font color='#FF000'>Je moet alles invullen</font>";

}

elseif  ($pinda !== $invulcijfer){
    echo "<font color='#FF000'>Dat zijn geen cijfers</font>";
} else {

   if ($pinda == $lotnummer) {

echo "<font color='green'>WAUW! Het is je gelukt!</font>";
  }
  else {
  
  echo "<font color='#FF000'>Sorry, het is niet gelukt..</font>";

  
 // Maybe update query van dat ze - points hebben ofso? q wat jij wilt
        }
    }
 }
?>
<br><br>
<h3>Loterij Script</h3>
<font color="green">Typ 4 cijfers in en misschien win jij!</font><br><br>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" maxlength="4"/><br>
<input type="text" id="cijfer" name="cijfer" maxlength="4"/><br>
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Check je lot"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @wouterdz I ran your code minus the extra closing brace and I did not get an error. Is there any other code above what you posted as a question?

Comment: Well that's really weird, no other code above it. Maybe you could send me a pastebin with the code you edited?

Comment: @wouterdz I will add the entire code that I ran underneath my answer.

Comment: Now it does work, thanks for your time. Your my hero for today ;)

Comment: @wouterdz I don't quite understand how your code is supposed to work, if I knew what the words were, I might be able to work with it a bit more. Yet, it's not giving me any `Unexpected T_Variable` error.

Comment: you're sorry for that mistake haha

Comment: @wouterdz I spotted another error in `if (isset($_POST['sumbitBtn']))` it needs to read as `if (isset($_POST['submitBtn']))` there was a spelling mistake.

Comment: @wouterdz I found another syntax error. This `if($invulcijfer = '') {` needs to be `if($invulcijfer == '') {` and your script will work perfectly. I translated the text to see what it meant and now I know 100%. I will make the change in my answer, completely.